# Immediate index definition

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, constraints

What does it mean for an index to be 'immediate' ?

I'm referring to 'index' in the SQL standards, but perhaps more specifically as per this [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-index.html).

Comment: I did see the defintion, but still dont understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indicate when the constraint check is applied.  From the documentation on constraints:

*SET CONSTRAINTS sets the behavior of constraint checking within the current transaction. IMMEDIATE constraints are checked at the end of each statement. DEFERRED constraints are not checked until transaction commit. Each constraint has its own IMMEDIATE or DEFERRED mode.*

A UNIQUE index is a also a constraint so this applies.